# Selecting individual Nodes from query-xml to API

Tags: c#, xml, api, sdk

I have previously achieved this using an xml file with:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load("fileString.xml");
```

The query-xml I am using connects to an API and returns results, however I an having trouble selecting individual nodes because the xml is not a file so the previous way is not working.

Does anyone know how to achieve this using query-xml?

Code is: `const string hostname = "*****";
            const string username = "******";
            const string password = "******";

```
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;

        var client = new InformationServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_InformationService",
                                                  string.Format("https://{0}:17778/SolarWinds/InformationService/OrionBasic", hostname));
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
        client.Open();

        var result = client.QueryXml("SELECT TOP 1 A.AlertDefID, I.Status, I.Node, A.ActiveObject, A.ObjectType, A.Acknowledged, A.AcknowledgedBy, A.AcknowledgedTime, A.TriggerTimeOffset, A.TriggerTimeStamp FROM Orion.AlertStatus A INNER JOIN Orion.Interface I ON A.ID = I.ID WHERE A.Acknowledged = 0 RETURN XML AUTO", null);
        `
```

Comment: I have done it the same way as before but used   XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml); for the string instead of file

Answer (score 0):

Do you just need to load the string into an xml document?

You can do the following...

```
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(xmlString);
```